# Obtendo um arquivo binario e guardando ele novamente

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou fazendo um teste com um código simples, mas esta dando erro. Quero simplesmente obter o conteúdo de um arquivo binário que é uma imagem (jpg), e guardar ele novamente com outro nome.

Meu código é esse:

```
    String content = null;

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\farol.jpg"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;
    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
        builder.append((char) ch);
    }
    in.close();
    content = builder.toString();


    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\farolNOVO.jpg"));
    out.write(content);
    out.close();
```

A imagem "farolNOVO.jpg" esta sendo criada, com a dimensão correta e o mesmo tamanho da original, só que ela fica toda estranha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem original é essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

OBS 1: Esse código está funcionando para arquivos .txt
OBS 2: Estou usando o java 1.6 (não posso atualiza-lo por questões de compatibilidade com outras coisas por aqui)

Fazendo outros testes por aqui, achei um que funcionou em partes:

```
String FILE_ORINNAL = "C:\\farol.jpg";
    String FILE_NOVO = "C:\\faro_novo.jpg";

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(FILE_ORINNAL);
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NOVO);

    int byteRead;

    while ((byteRead = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(byteRead);
    }
```

O problema é que esse esta lendo e passando direto para o outputStream.
Eu queria fazer um metodo "getContentFileBinary" que retorna-se a String do contteudo binario.
Depois quero fazer outro metodo "getContentFileBinaryBase64"

Esse é meu objetivo final.

Comment: Você quer manter o arquivo antigo? Você precisa ler o conteúdo do arquivo?

Comment: O arquivo antigo pra min tanto faz. Eu to apenas tentando ler um arquivo binário e guardando ele de novo para teste. Esse código é um pedaço do meu script,  depois vou codificar ele em base64 e fazer outras coisas. Mas já estou com problema nesse ponto.

Comment: Não poste a resposta no corpo da pergunta, use o botão responder e adicione na resposta a sua solução `outputStream.write(content.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")); Esse "ISO-8859-1" resolveu meu problema!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O meu problema estava no momento de criar o arquivo. Depois que utilizei o "ISO-8859-1" funcionou.

```
outputStream.write(content.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Esse "ISO-8859-1" resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente a leitura esta perdendo algo, você pode tentar ler o conteudo usando isto:

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

...

Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("", "C:\\farol.jpg");
byte [] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(p);
```

E depois gravar:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

...

FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\farolNOVO.jpg");
try {
    stream.write(fileData);
} finally {
    stream.close();
}
```

Efetuei o teste com isto:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Path caminho = Paths.get("c:\\farol.jpg");

        byte [] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(caminho);

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\farolNOVO.jpg");
        try {
            stream.write(fileData);
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Copiando arquivos

No entanto eu acho algo bastante redundante ter que ler o conteúdo e copiar o arquivo, já que será uma cópia indentica, se este for mesmo o objetivo, apenas copiar sugiro usa o [`File.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).

- `static long copy(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options)`

  Copia os bytes de um inputstream para um arquivo
- `static long copy(Path source, OutputStream out)`

  Copia os bytes de um arquivo para um outputstream.
- `static Path copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`

  Copia um arquivo para outro arquivo

Exemplo de uso para substituir se já existir arquivo na pasta:

```
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;

...

Path caminho = Paths.get("c:\\farol.jpg");
Path destrino = Paths.get("c:\\farolNOVO.jpg");

Files.copy(caminho, destrino, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Acho que eu n tenho a classe "Path"

Comment: @AndersonSouza `java.nio.file` esta disponivel desde o Java7

Comment: Não tenho isso: import java.nio.file.......

Comment: @AndersonSouza qual o seu Java? Você deve estar bem desatualizado

Comment: Sim, mas eu estou usando o java 1.6 :(

Comment: Eu comentei no final da minha pergunta ali, acho que vou colocar no inicio kkkk pois java 1.6 eh bem velho já

Answer (score 0):

### Java 6 ou menor

Em versões anteriores ou iguais ao Java 6 você pode fazer assim:

```
File original = new File("c:\\farol.jpg");
if(!original.exists()) {
    throw new IOException("O arquivo especificado não existe!");    
}

File novo = new File("c:\\farolNOVO.jpg");
if(novo.exists()) {
    throw new IOException("Já existe um arquivo com esse nome");
 }

original.renameTo(novo);
```

### Java 7

Em versões iguais ou maiores ao Java 7 você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
File original = new File("c:\\farol.jpg");
if(!original.exists()) {
    throw new IOException("O arquivo especificado não existe!");    
}

File novo = new File("c:\\farolNOVO.jpg");
if(novo.exists()) {
    throw new IOException("Já existe um arquivo com esse nome");
 }

Files.move(original.toPath(), 
        novo.toPath(), 
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: obrigado por ajudar, mas eu preciso obter o conteudo do arquivo. Esse meu exemplo foi de teste. Depois vou converter ele em base64. Então eu preciso obter o conteudo do arquivo